# Sockets Connector - is there any way to read data instead of send and receive - Mule 4

Tags: sockets, tcp, tcpclient, mulesoft, mule-connector

There is a requirement.

We have to connect to tcp server. We are acting as a client. Will initiate a logon massage to tcp server. After successful logon they going to push data to that tcp server. So here we have to read that data posted on particular server. and to maintain the connection we need respond back to their echo massages.

But the problem is mulesoft we have the send and receive connector. So after 1 call thread is getting killed. Here need a solution that it has to read in case new message in that particular tcp socket.

Note: will not able to use the socket listener here because we are not exposing any socket packet here. we are not acting as server.

Comment: Receive and read are the same thing. Unclear what you’re asking.

Comment: Note that there is nothing called MuleSoft 4. The company is called MuleSoft, and their product is Mule 4.

Comment: Mule 4 contains not just one but *six* `read()` methods. 30 seconds in Google.

Comment: I need guidance on how to read data from a TCP connection. My project involves receiving data from TCP, processing it, and then sending a response back to the TCP servers with same reference number. However, I haven’t found a receive operation in the Sockets Connector. Could you advise on how to implement a read function in Mule 4?

Comment: You haven't explain your use case with enough detail. Edit you question to add details.

Comment: I can only repeat. Receive and read are the same thing, and there are *six* `read()` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MuleSoft Sockets Connector for Mule 4 does not support persistent connections. As an alternative you could create your own connector in Java code with the [Mule SDK](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/latest/getting-started) to support this use case.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is i have to connect provider tcp server. So not able to use listener here.

Comment: So we are doing tibco to mule migration. In tibco they used read tcp data connector to get the data. For every request have the reference number. And process that data send back to tcp server using write tcp data.

Comment: So to implement the same i need only connector which can read data from the provider tcp server. But in mule we have only send and receive socket connector. So if im  using it, they getting empty in-proper massages and request timeout for actual massages. Because we are using isobitmap here

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to do. My answer is based on the question, which didn't mention details. Instead of adding comments please edit your question and explain the use case in more detail. Include examples of inputs, outputs, use case, code or pseudocode, diagrams, etc. to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: could you please check, just now edited my question.

Comment: I updated the answer now that the use case is clearer.